# Best practise to implement TouchId authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, touch-id

I want to implement Touch ID authentication when the user accesses my App(like Evernote). When the user opens my App & if Touch ID is enabled then ask for the Touch ID and continue.

If I check for Touch ID authentication in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method then it is also called after any OS generated alert(e.g Asking for Notification, Contacts permission etc). So my app is also asking for Touch ID when any permission popup appears.

Please suggest me in which `Appdelegate` method I should check for authenticate user?

Comment: I want to implement Applock like Evernote. So what is the suitable AppDelegate method to check for authentication?

Comment: use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and once your authentication is over then add the some bool value in userdefault, if it is false of userdefault call your LAContext

Comment: It will work if I have to authenticate only 1 time. But I need to authenticate whenever my app comes to foreground.

Comment: then add in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didbecomeactive mode

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thanks for ur reply. Can you please elaborate its working? And I can achieve this by checking 2 times but I want to know how can I achieve this by checking 1 time.

Comment: what is one time or two time and which language you except the OP in objective C or swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164813/discussion-between-user816-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't *applicationDidBecomeActive* a valid option for this? Other alerts asking for permissions should probably not happen until the user has authenticated.

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive will be called when any alert asking for permission is presented. E.g when you ask permission for Alert, user allows it, then applicationDidBecomeActive will be called and app will ask for Touch ID.

Comment: Ah I see your point. Are you keeping the state (whether the user is authenticated) anywhere in the app? You could log out the user on *applicationDidEnterBackground*, then on *applicationDidBecomeActive* authenticate the user only if he's been logged out.